# Swift 2 MKMapViewDelegate rendererForOverlay optionality

Tags: swift, mkmapviewdelegate

In Swift 1.2 I have this:

```
class UVC: NSViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    // ...

    // **************************************
    // MARK: MapView Delegate
    // **************************************
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is OSGBTiles {
            return OSGBTilesRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay as! OSGBTiles)
        } else if overlay is ESRI {
            return ESRIRenderer(shapeFileOverlay: overlay as! ESRI)
        } else if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
            return MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        } else {
            print("Unknown overlay")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Swift 2 has changed the definition of  `mapView:rendererForOverlay` to now return `MKOverlayRenderer` rather than `MKOverlayRenderer!`, and will not now allow me to return `nil` (unsurprisingly) as `MKOverlayRenderer` is not `NilLiteralConvertible`. However, the documentation (in Xcode 7) still says:

> Return Value
>
> The renderer to use when presenting the specified overlay
>   on the map. If you return nil, no content is drawn for the specified
>   overlay object.

What am I supposed to return if passed an overlay that I don't recognise?

Answer (score 2):

According to the most recent MKMapView.h, the new function declaration is now:

```
// Current renderer for overlay; returns nil if the overlay is not shown.
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
func rendererForOverlay(overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer?
```

Comment: Not sure of which function you speak. I'm speaking about the protocol function
 `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer!`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. It's interesting that even the ObjC version of this specifies a non-null return. I'm continuing to look for the answer to this...

Comment: Actually I just filed bug #21581742 on this.

Comment: This is a follow-up to Bug ID# 21581742.   

Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the following information: 

The only overlays which will be passed into this will be overlays that a you've added; There's no such thing as an "unrecognized overlay". Developers must provide a renderer if they add an overlay -- that's how the API works.

We consider this issue closed.  If you have any questions or concern regarding this issue, please update your report directly (http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for researching this @MarkKnopper!