# Nil is incompatible with return type 'MKOverlayRenderer'

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift2

I am getting this error

> **"Nil is incompatible with return type 'MKOverlayRenderer'"**.

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKCircle {
      let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
      circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
      circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
      circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
      return circleRenderer
    }
      return nil
  }
```

why is it occurring?

Answer (score 15):

return MKPolylineRenderer() instead of returning nil.

Comment: I did a hybrid of the suggestions here; 
    `NSAssert([myOverlay isKindOfClass:[MyOverlay class], @"some message about %@", myOverlay);
    return [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:myOverlay];
`
This was the best of both worlds, catching my error but suppressing the XCode warning about not returning something of correct type.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be answered here:

[Swift 2 MKMapViewDelegate rendererForOverlay optionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750560/swift-2-mkmapviewdelegate-rendererforoverlay-optionality)

You are just not allowed to return nil. Your overlay *must* have a renderer. Replace "return nil" with an assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You are not suppose to return `nil` for this delegate function. The map view is expecting a render for each of the overlays. In your case, you should do this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 
{
    assert(overlay is MKCircle, "overlay must be circle")

    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
    return circleRenderer
}
```

I don't think you should return `MKPolylineRenderer()` because it may hide your bug .

Answer (score 1):

Because nil is not an MKOverlayRenderer. If you expect that a function might return nil, then the return type should be an optional. As defined, the function can only return actual MKOverlayRenderer's.

Comment: what should i use instead of nil?

Comment: @milo526 optional means? can you explain briefly?

Comment: Optionals are values that can either be nil or a value of the type. When declaring an optional you should add a `?` to the type declaration. `let myString:String?` declares a variable of type `String` which can be a string or nil.

Comment: @milo526: It's a delegate method of MKMapView, so changing the return value to optional is not doable. Second option is best in this case.

Comment: @Mithun MP when i used string optional, i got this error. **Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'MKOverlayRenderer'**

Comment: ... you asked me to explain what optionals where. The String optional was just an example you should in your case use an MKOverlayRenderer optional thus using `MKOverlayRenderer?`

Comment: i have already tried that and got this error **Variable 'myrender' captured by a closure before being initialized**